# React-query hook imported into a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

Having the following hook:

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import axios from 'axios';

export const useGetData = () => {
  const query = 'getData';

  const { isLoading, isError, data, error, refetch, isSuccess } = useQuery(
    query,
    async () => {
      const { data } = await axios(
        'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random'
      );
      return data;
    }
  );

  return {
    data,
    isError,
    isLoading,
    error,
    refetch,
    isSuccess,
  };
};

export default useGetData;
```

For the beginning, I want to import it into a component and check the values of `data`, `isError` and others.

Here is the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';
import useGetData from './components/use-get-data';
const queryClient = new QueryClient({});

function App() {
  const { data, isLoading } = useGetData();
  console.log('data: ', data);
  console.log('isLoading: ', isLoading);
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <div className='container'></div>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It throws the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one
    at useQueryClient
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Your call to your hook need to be under the query client provider to access his context.
So you need to put it in a component called as a child of QueryClientProvider

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `useGetData` custom hook in the descendants component of the `QueryClientProvider` provider so that you can use `useQuery` hook.

Because `useQuery` hook use `useQueryClient` hook underly, see [source code](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/blob/7aadd6896dd8a36e3f4ff8e7153a080528807d03/src/react/useBaseQuery.ts#L30), and `useQueryClient` use `useContext` hook underly, source code:

```
export const useQueryClient = () => {
  const queryClient = React.useContext(
    getQueryClientContext(React.useContext(QueryClientSharingContext))
  )

  if (!queryClient) {
    throw new Error('No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one')
  }

  return queryClient
}
```

`queryClient` context comes from `QueryClientProvider` so that `useContext` can get it.